# Read Pyspark Dataframe from CSV with different timestamp/date format

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a CSV file that I need to read with Pyspark.

The CSV has various date and timestamp fields with timestamp format `yyyyMMddHHmmss` and date `yyyMMdd`.

Now I need to declare the schema with `StructType([StructField()])`, can I use the `DateType()` and
`TimestampType()` for those fields? Or I will have problem with my format?

Comment: for the format `yyyyMMddHHmmss` and `yyyMMdd`, they are in the same column?

Comment: Sorry different columns, It wasn't really clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateType` for date and `TimestampType` for datetime. Additionally, you need to provide `dateFormat` and `timestampFormat` options as mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html).

```
schema = StructType([StructField('datetime_col', TimestampType()), StructField('date_col', DateType())])

df = spark.read.option("header", True).option("dateFormat", "yyyyMMdd").option("timestampFormat", "yyyyMMddHHmmss").schema(schema).csv("/content/sample_data/test.csv")

df.show(truncate=False)

+---------------+------------+
|datetime_col   |date_col    |
+---------------+------------+
|20221103191500 |20221103    |
+---------------+------------+


df.printSchema()

root
 |-- datetime_col: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_col: string (nullable = true)
```

Sample CSV file used:

```
datetime_col, date_col
20221103191500, 20221103
```

Comment: @ DuccioBorchi, did this solution work for you?